# Sweetalert2 confirm dialog text with resource value ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I want to use the sweetalert2 confirm dialog by ASP.NET webform but I need use message and title from my resource file. I also add this

```
Resources:resource,SweetAlert_Delete_Title
```

in my resource file. But when I use this code, it's not working at all. Also when I use the quotation, I mean like this

```
'<%$ Resources:resource,SweetAlert_Delete_Title%>**'
```

it's also show me the exactly `Resources:resource,SweetAl...`.

So how can I use it?

Thanks

```
<asp:Button ID="Btn_Delete" CssClass="btn btn-danger" runat="server" 
     Text="Delete" 
     OnClientClick="return sweetAlertConfirm(this,<%$ Resources:resource,SweetAlert_Delete_Title%>,<%$ Resources:resource,SweetAlert_Delete_Text%>);" 
     OnClick="Btn_Delete_Click" />
```

Comment: thanks for answering dear. but my problem is only to get message text from resource. nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two issues here.

First this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Btn_Delete" CssClass="btn btn-danger" runat="server" 
     Text="Delete" 
    OnClientClick="return sweetAlertConfirm(this,<%$ Resources:resource,SweetAlert_Delete_Title%>,<%$ Resources:resource,SweetAlert_Delete_Text%>);" 
 OnClick="Btn_Delete_Click" />
```

The problem is when you click on this button, BOTH the server side code (and post-back) will run. So, it may well "appear" this is not working.

Remember, with the exception of js alert(), and confirm(), then the sweet alert does NOT halt, nor wait. It runs asynchronous.

I think you should put in the js references for sweet alert, and test this code. I don't think the "resource" issue has anything to do with this code not working.

In fact, you can't even use a js "await" command, since as noted, the INSTANT you click your button, the sweet alter routine does NOT halt, and that sweet alert code will 100% run, pop the dialog AND ALSO HAVE returned true or false.

So, the REAL problem, the REAL question then is how to get sweet alert based on user input to trigger a true/false return, and thus run (or not run) the server side code. this issue is MUCH larger then your resource file issue.

It is possible you addressed the above issue, but it not at all clear if you have.

lets fix this first issue, and THEN move to working on the resource file issue.

Your code needs to be like this:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="alert test"
            OnClientClick="return mydelprompt(this)"
            OnClick="Button1_Click"
            />

        <script>

            var myok = false
            function mydelprompt(btn) {

                if (myok) {
                    return true
                }

                swal({
                    title: "Are you sure?",
                    text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
                    icon: "warning",
                    buttons: true,
                    dangerMode: true,
                })
                    .then((willDelete) => {
                        if (willDelete) {
                            myok = true
                            btn.click()
                        }
                    });

                return false

            }
```

Note how we return false when the alert is triggered.

So, here is what occures.

You click on the button. Client side js code runs, RETURNS FALSE!!!!
Dialog IS THEN displayed!!!!!

Now, when the user hits cancel, we do nothing. However, when we click ok (to confirm), then we set our global js var myok = true, and THEN click the button again!!! The button click fires, our js function runs again, but this time, it returns true, and thus the server side button click code now runs.

So, if you resolved the above, and your 100% sure the above is working, then and only then can we start to address the resource file issue - and due to above, your resource file use might well be ok, it just that you not seeing this work due to the button click always doing a post-back